# Amazon AMI selection

Tags: amazon-ec2

I just found out about amazon EC2. I am wondering what it actually offers. I use to go with VPS servers and now I want to learn if EC2 give me the same options as a VPS with some host company.

Are there any limitations on what I can install?

Thanks
Cristian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the main difference between EC2 and a conventional VPS hosting service is the pricing model. EC2 charges for CPU time (and other resources) by the hour, whereas many conventional services charge by the month (or greater). The best way to learn about EC2 would be to jump into the [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/), and then sign up for the [free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).

Within reason, there are no limitations on what you can install.